# Scroll UIScrollView to a fixed range

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a little question about `UIScrollView` properties, I have a scroll view on my view and 2 objects. My ScrollView is 960 pixel high.

If I scroll down over the half I would that the view jump to the end of the ScrollView.

Yes, it is hard to explain :-D

An Example:

I'm scrolling..then I'm over the half and then the `UIScrollView` jump directly to a fixed range.  I have no ideas, maybe you have some information or some snippets of code :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have `[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];`?

Comment: Oh I thought this only works if I scroll right/left. 
Thx

Comment: Alright I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening because you are setting paging to be enabled. If you don't want paging, don't add the line

```
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

or

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```